# Can't download a file from application folder in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a grid view. The data bound to the grid view. I have a column with download link button. When I click on download the file should be downloaded but I got some issue while tying it.

I uploaded files to application folder and the path to database but when I try to download the file it fires an error

```
    LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
    GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    string filePath = gridView1.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filePath + "\"");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));
    Response.End();
```

[image]

But my application folder has the uploaded file

[image]

Comment: Use this: `Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("/documents/mini/"+filePath));` (instead of your line).

Comment: Is there any other way rather than this..?

Answer (score 2):

Your file path is wrong. Server is looking for the file in the site root, here: `C:\Users\lagis\Downloads\templgarden\jhvgdfjka.txt`. But it seems your desired file is in `/documents/mini`. So, you need to use the right path(url) for `Server.TransmitFile` like this:

```
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("/documents/mini/" + filePath));
```